# apply background image to bootstrap columns grid layout

Tags: html, css, gridview

I'm new to css and bootstrap, I'm trying to have a 3 column webpage, where left and right will be empty columns with a pattern image background, and content in between. When trying to to it with bootstrap's grid layout I only get a straight line at the top of the page.

```
    <body>
    <div class="container-fluid text-center">
        <div class="row-content">
        <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-image:url('108.png');
            background-repeat:repeat;"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <h1>Welcome</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
                elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore 
                magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea 
                commodo consequat. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,
                sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
                consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore 
                et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                quis nostrud exercitation ullamco 
                laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            </div>
             <div class="col-sm-2" style="background-image:url('108.png');
        background-repeat:repeat;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

So I want these left and right columns to be as long as the content in the middle instead of a straight line at the top.
Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Tables are great, they'll work on most things - you should still test anyway. But they are reliable.

```
.row-content {
display: table;
}

.row-content > div {
display: table-cell;
}
```

Have a little play, do some more research into css. You have to think about the life of the code you are writing - read books, research online, do everything you can to know everything possible about css :)

Comment: well would tables still be responsive ? I read that they're not